# Plugin: WP e-Commerce Errors immediately after activating plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress plugin Duplicator followed all instructions but I get this when I transfer it on a temporary website page.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/public_html/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce-product-showroom/wp_e_showrp.php:469)
>   in
>   /home/public_html/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/public_html/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce-product-showroom/wp_e_showrp.php:469)
>   in
>   /home/public_html/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/public_html/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce-product-showroom/wp_e_showrp.php:469)
>   in
>   /home/public_html/temp/home/public_html/temp/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 866

Then I read some solutions posted in wordpress forums:
Solution:

Create a php5.ini and save it in your root folder. If you have various websites under one server, then it will be saved where you can view all the websites' folders.

Create a folder in the root named "tmp" (without "s)

> Type this inside the php5.ini :
>
> session.save_path = "/home/content/##/#######/html/tmp"
>   upload_tmp_dir=/tmp
>
> *The #s are replaced by what your hosting provider gave you. In Godaddy, when you enter your Hosting Control Center it will be the
>   Absolute Hosting Path under Server.

They said it worked but not for me. Can you help me identify where my save_path?
Is this solution really working? Do you have any other option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To find your absolute path which is needed for your save_path, log in to your Hosting Control Center. Once logged in you will see the Server column in the middle of the page. At the bottom of this column is your absolute path. Simply append /tmp to the end of this after creating the folder in your root.